# Read it carefully

Tags: riddle, word, literature

My prefix is found in an automobile,
My infix corrects a mistake with mistakes,
My suffix is practice if you're very old.
My whole may be found unexpectedly.

Hint:

> My infix is not spelled correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My prefix is found in an automobile

> liter - as in units of gasoline. US usage as also in automobile, though gallons would be used.

My infix corrects a mistake with mistakes

> eratu - an erratum corrects a mistake and there are two spelling mistakes. Also by the hint.

My suffix is practice if you're very old

> [ure](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ure) - an old word for practice

My whole may be found unexpectedly

> **literature** - it is the last word, as a tag, in the riddle.

Title: Read it carefully

> literature is read, and carefully as the word appears attached to the question

---

Second washed-up attempt: My prefix is found in an automobile

> water - added to battery acid, radiator coolant and windscreen washer detergent.

My infix corrects a mistake with mistakes

> [erf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) -  applied to a single measurement (not exact - a mistake) of a normal distribution, gives a range and a probability it lies in range, so corrects a mistake to two mistakes, using mistakes.

My suffix is practice if you're very old.

> fall - practice meaning to do often, and old age increases the risk of falling.

My whole may be found unexpectedly.

> waterfall- famous ones, such as the Angel Falls, were  rediscovered unexpectedly by foreigners.

<sub>No explanation of the title or the literature tag, so no high hopes, though the question may get other responses, or a hint.</sub>

---

First failed try: My prefix is found in an automobile,

> rev -  a turn of the engine

My infix corrects a mistake with mistakes,

> revoc - cover up, efforts to fix a mistake, leading to a litany of mistakes

My suffix is practice if you're very old.

> vocation - one's life's work, practice being your work

My whole may be found unexpectedly.

> revocation - cancellation or calling off something, usually unplanned

Read it carefully

> literature tag - :)

I think this answer will be annulled by Rand.

Comment: Sorry, annulling this answer. The infix in particular is a stretch (although my intended answer is also a bit dodgy in the infix), and also the "found unexpectedly" part.

Comment: @Rand - I propose this edit to the question  'My prefix is one found in an automobile, my infix follows a mistake with a more mistakes, my suffix is what the old may have practised, I often am unexpected. '

Comment: Oh, I hadn't seen your latest edit. That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Prefix=Auto ->(auto)mobile 
infix= S -> Mistake(s)
suffix= -> MD (old practice was Medicine from MD)
whole=found (maybe :)

Autofoundsmd

Comment: ... is "autofoundsmd" a word?

Comment: @Randal'Thor I have *no idea* ...